# Open source multiplayer games for Android?

Tags: android, open-source, multiplayer

Please pardon me if this has been asked before, but I'm wondering if there are any good open source multiplayer games for Android. What I'm trying to get is a game that where network latency is important (for example, multiplayer FPS games).

I came across mages game engine, but it doesn't seem like it has some demo games. I would like to avoid developing the game if possible, since my focus is on the network part, ie. to see how poor network can affect multiplayer games.

Thanks a lot!

Edit: I just found out about andengine. Seems like it supports multiplayer gaming. I would be really grateful if anyone can point me to an implementation of a multiplayer game (if any). The example in the andengine is not really suitable for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up modifying andEngine. I stripped out the multiplayer part and made it a normal desktop java application running in the cloud.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what kind of multiplayer capability you would like to implement (or examine). If you look at andEngine, you can see an example of close proximity multiplayer capability, meaning that the users would have to be on the same WiFi network (they have to have unique IP addresses).

Another method to implement multiplayer would be on top of mobile networks. A good example for this you can find in the Skiller SDK ( http://dev.skiller-games.com ). With the SDK you can find a TicTacToe example that you can actually run on two different devices.

Either way, achieving real time multiplayer capability (for FPS) on top of mobile network would be extremely difficult since that network's latency depends on many things and elements in the network (ex. Wap-Gateway, infogine, and other elements).

Hope i have helped.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the info about Skiller SDK! BTW, andEngine multiplayer doesn't require you to be on the same network if you can provide a public IP to the server.